# Isn't it the same character?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, actor-identification

I've just watched [Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/) and have noticed an interesting thing.

Here's Bruce Wayne's parents killer:

[image]

And here's a bad guy — one of Martha's guardians:

[image]

Isn't it the same guy? More mature on the second photo, of course. Or, which is more realistic in terms of age, it is a son of the first guy.

Is it possible that Bruce got his revenge, but even did not notice that? Or is it just a similar actor?

Comment: I'm actually struggling to find out who even played these characters in *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice* at the moment (there is nothing for Joe Chill on IMDb), so I've asked /r/DC_Cinematic for help and linked to this question. I think you may be on to something though.

Comment: "More mature", you mean, like, about 40 years later?

Comment: It seems that the actor is unknown and is remaining uncredited, which means it'll be super difficult, if not impossible, to find out his identity. Unfortunately, reverse searching those images makes google search for "Soldier" and "Gun" because of the dark & brooding lighting style that DC is going for. If anybody can find out who either guy is or if they're the same person, kudos to them, and they should probably seek out a job as a professional detective.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach, )) that's why I'm interested in possibility) Maybe it's just an easter egg)

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach, and btw it can also be a son of the first guy) He looks ike his father, which is possible, and his age semm to be correct.

Comment: @DrRDizzle, thanks.

Comment: “I've just watched Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice and have noticed an interesting thing.” That’s the real achievement here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it would be the same exact guy, just from a logical standpoint (was a plot point). Sadly, [neither is credited](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/fullcredits/) anywhere and/or they don't have a pic in IMDB to match against. But here's <s>Joe Chill</s> some guy with a gun from a different angle ([source](http://io9.gizmodo.com/lets-break-down-all-the-secrets-in-batman-v-supermans-1717576234))

[image]

The resemblance is diminished from this angle. Also, he appears to be darker complexioned (although that could be the lighting too). The guy with the machine gun appears to be fairer skinned.